# SVG colouring - why does that not work?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to color a part of a svg-file by css and that doesn't seem to work. 
This is the svgs' code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="logo" viewBox="0 0 87.6 128.2"><title>  sw17_rebrand_logo</title><path class="logo_top" d="M15.6 86.9C-1.8 71-6.4 37.2 16 14.9S72-2.5 87.6 14.7Z"/><path class="logo_bottom" d="M72.3 41.2c20.2 19.2 19.5 53.7-1.5 73.2-22.5 21-55.4 16-70.9-1.1Z"/></svg>
```

And that's the css

```
.logo_top{
    fill:blue;
}
```

The html looks like that

```
 <a href="#" class="logo"><img class="logo_img" src="images/sw17_rebrand-logo.svg"/></a>
```

But that doesn't do nothing. I don't even see that particular css-code in Webdev Tools. If I put the code (style="fill:blue") directly into the svg, this works, but that's not the way I need it here.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put the svg in the html, not as src.

Comment: See here: https://svgontheweb.com/#css take particular note of the ability to include(link) them in an `<object>` tag, and the interactivity this affords.

Comment: CSS does not work across different documents and the image is a separate document.

Answer (score -1):

As both comments already answered that question 100% - I'll just sum that up to get the question closed:

a) You can either put the svg directly into html instead of linking with `<img>` to it. That way coloring with svg as in my question works smooth.
b) You manipulate your svgs' sourcecode a bit by appending that code

```
// Add to very start of SVG file before <svg>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
```

to the file(s). That way you can still use `<img src="the.svg"...`

Comment: You can't use an external file as a CSS stylesheet if you're displaying SVG via an <img> tag. You'd have to URL encode the stylesheet and embed it in the SVG file itself.